# List Transformation of Routes in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a routes list like this:

```
routes= 
[[(0, 1), (1, 6), (6, 7), (7, 10), (10, 9), (9, 0)],
 [(0, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0)],
 [(0, 8), (8, 0)]]
```

Route 1 is from 0 to 1 to 6 to 7 and so on ....
how can i transform this list into a list like this:

```
routes_new= [[0, 1, 6, 7, 10, 9, 0], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0],[0,8,0]]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove duplicates from a list, while preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-while-preserving-order)

Comment: I don't know how to solve

Comment: "don't know how" <> "won't even try"

Comment: @Rabinzel Looks different to me, as this seems to include cycles which would give the wrong result when simply deduping. But still it's probably a duplicate.

Comment: You need to give more context. Are the routes always going to be ordered? Is the problem just to remove the common nodes between edges? The question is quite vague

Comment: True, just saw that myself when trying out the solutions. also if a route would return to a point where it has already been, the solutions in the link would just cut it.

Comment: First example shows routes are *not* always ordered.

Comment: the ids are not ordered, but the chunks are

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for [cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)#:%7E:text=In%20graph%20theory%2C%20a%20cycle,and%20last%20vertices%20are%20equal.) here, which seems to be the case, a simple way to achieve what you want is using NetworkX's `nx.simple_cycles`. This does not require for the edges to be ordered.

```
import networkx as nx

routes= [[(0, 1), (1, 6), (6, 7), (7, 10), (10, 9), (9, 0)],
 [(0, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0)],
 [(0, 8), (8, 0)]]

paths = []
for route in routes:
    G = nx.from_edgelist(route, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
    paths.append(list(nx.simple_cycles(G)))

paths
# [[[0, 1, 6, 7, 10, 9]], [[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]], [[0, 8]]]
```

If there can be multiple cycles in each route, check other functions in the cycle module, like [`nx.find_cycle`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.find_cycle.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.find_cycle), which allow you to specify an origin.

Comment: I started to write a networkx solution and got caught IRL, would have been something similar (I suspect however that it might be overkill) ;) +1

Comment: In my experience networkx is handy at simplifying solutions. When a problem translates to a graph equivalent, there's probably a simple solution :) In most cases at least

Comment: Btw, you can directly use `nx.from_edgelist(route, create_using=nx.DiGraph)`. Enables a list comprehension: `[next(nx.simple_cycles(nx.from_edgelist(r, create_using=nx.DiGraph)), []) for r in routes]` ;)

Comment: True! let's add that then @mozway

Comment: I can't see any value added to the answer by including that one liner. If anything it makes it less readable. Leaving it as it was @mozway

Comment: as you want (I thought you wanted me to add it, I realize my comment edit might have crossed your response). For a personal point of view however I find such lists comprehensions usually more readable than `append` in a loop. Btw, note that your output if different from OP's provided one.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the extensive list comprehension readability vs multiple lines. For a simple case I would agree. The cycles don't include the origin in the end, yes. I imagine OP might find that simple enough if it is required @mozway

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension can help you flatten your lists:

```
routes_new = [[t[0] for t in l]+[l[-1][1]] for l in routes]
```

*NB. this is assuming the edges are in order and linked. No check is performed. If this is not the case, please provide such an example.*

output:

```
[[0, 1, 6, 7, 10, 9, 0], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0], [0, 8, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the first number of each tuple and add the very last one for each route :

```
routes_new = [[val[0] for val in route] + [route[-1][-1]] for route in routes]
```

Comment: This adds no value to the already posted answer